# VS2010: Loading symbols from dlls very slow

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, symbols

I have a program which I am working on my Dell Laptop XPS 502X. At work, I usually have another monitor plugged in my DVI port and everything is fine. When I work from home, I only have the laptop screen. When I start the program in VS2010, it is very slow and I notice in the bottom of the screen `Loading symbols for ...\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detourel.dll...` which takes around 10-20 seconds every time. Any idea on why this is happening ?

EDIT:

I thought it was a drivers problem, but now it happens again.

I tried the ideas posted in similar questions

-DeleteAllBreakpoints stuff, didn't work.

-No remote symbols fetch or network path

-Enabled Just My Code

Looks like a hook DLL injected by the graphics drivers... driving me crazy!

EDIT 2:

The problem happens on and off, today everything seems find, yesterday, I even noticed it was slow loading the GROOVEEX.dll while the program was running when I was starting a CFileDialog. So it might not just be something related to the graphics drivers.

Comment: Same problem (me with VS2005) ... mighty annoying this is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like nVidia's use of the Detours library from Microsoft. Hopefully this will help...

http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=212704

and

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/

Run the msconfig tool that is built into Windows to take a look at some of the things that nVidia launches at startup. You may want to try disabling some of the startup items temporarily, but you'll want to research what each item you disable is before doing so, or you may have to go into safe mode to get back to a good state.